# How to restore a stack installed from debian

Tags: ros, debian, ros-diamondback, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I accidentally completely deleted all the packages in my diamondback/stacks directory - the packages like [common] and [vision_opencv] and [openni_kinect] and all those important things. It was a tremendously stupid thing to do, I know, but there it is. Can anyone explain to me how to get back all those packages? I tried installing diamondback again in the hopes that it would reinstall the whole stack, but it didn't work. Then I tried things like "sudo apt-get install common" to try to install the packages back one by one, manually, but that didn't work either, so apparently I'm missing a lot of the fine details about installing packages. I really don't understand ROS or Ubuntu well enough yet to work my way back out of this - any help please?
Thanks,
Khiya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10211/how-to-restore-a-stack-installed-from-debian/) by [Khiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/669/khiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use the reinstall option, i.e. `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ros-diamondback-<whatever you need>`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reinstalling should work. Try removing first:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-diamondback-*
```

And then installing from binaries (more detailed instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu)):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2